# Green's function simplification

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I'm reading the chapter on Green's functions in Strauss' PDE book. He gives the Green's function for the sphere as:

$$ G(\textbf{x}, \textbf{x}_o) = - \frac{1}{4 \pi |\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_o|}+ \frac{a}{4 \pi |\textbf{x}_o| | \textbf{x}-\textbf{x}^{*}_o | }          $$

where $\textbf{x}$ is the vector representing a point on the surface of the sphere, $\textbf{x}_o$ is the vector representing any point strictly inside the sphere, and $ \textbf{x}^*_o$ is defined as follows:

$$ \textbf{x}^*_{o} = \frac{a^2 \textbf{x}_o}{ |\textbf{x}_o |^2}   $$

Strauss then asserts that when $\textbf{x}_o  = \textbf{0}$ the formula reduces to

$$ G(\textbf{x}, \textbf{x}_o) = - \frac{1}{4 \pi |\textbf{x}|}+ \frac{1}{4 \pi a }          $$

How do I prove this? Is there any way to do this without using spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}$
$\newcommand{\c}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$
We see that:
\begin{align*}
|\x_0|^2|\x - \x_0^*|^2 &= |\x_0|^2\c{\x - \x_0^*,\x - \x_0^*} \\
&= |\x_0|^2(\c{\x,\x} - 2 \c{\x,\x_0^*} + \c{\x_0^*,\x_0^*}) \\
&= |\x_0|^2\left(\c{\x,\x} - 2 \c{\x,\frac{a^2\x_0}{|\x_0|^2}} + \c{\frac{a^2\x_0}{|\x_0|^2},\frac{a^2\x_0}{|\x_0|^2}}\right) \\
&= |\x_0|^2|\x|^2 - 2a^2\c{\x,\x_0} + \frac{a^4}{|\x_0|^2}\c{\x_0,\x_0} \\
&= |\x_0|^2|\x|^2 - 2a^2\c{\x,\x_0} + a^4 \\
\end{align*}
If $\x_0 = 0$, then $|\x_0|^2|\x|^2 = 0$ and $\c{\x,\x_0} = 0$, so we're left with:
$$
|\x_0||\x - \x_0^*| = a^2
$$
Substitute this back into the original Green's function identity and you get the identity you want.